# SHA-256 digest differ while length < 64 bytes

Tags: c, sha256, atsha204

UPDATE:

CryptoAuthLib solve the problem. Many thanks @zaph

I'm working on ATSHA204 security chip, where a part of work is to calculate SHA-256 alike the chip does. I'm using
`CryptoAuthentication ATSHA204A Development Library 2.0.1 [from hxxp://www.atmel.com/tools/CRYPTOAUTHENTICATIONATSHA204DEVELOPMENTLIBRARY.aspx]` Implemented in C.

Well, while try any data >= 64 bytes, everything works fine. But anything < 64 bytes differ with the CHIP's calculation.

Have a look below,

```
message: 
20 4D 56 EF 56 F6 27 71 
AD CF D7 07 FC BA BE 21 
A8 7D 7C AF F5 54 6F ED 
27 2C F9 ED 75 B3 94 C7 
1C 04 02 00 EE 01 23 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0E EA 11 36 8E 89 D2 11 
07 C1 1B 64 B6 D0 34 DA 
A6 DB 66 0F 14 FB DB C6 
26 7D 6A 3A 62 83 47 13

digest from Atmel's algorithm: 
8C E2 28 98 6A 21 A3 40 
A4 42 97 CE 4C 80 70 DF 
87 97 61 B3 FC CD A2 BF 
8D F0 89 EE 29 B8 68 BF
```

[image]
And while taking something < 64 length to same implementation,

```
message:
11 CC 32 8B 30 ED 04 81
73 96 A9 F8 3B F7 9E 72
23 DC 05 29 3C 65 36 70
3A 03 1C E2 C2 2D 99 4E
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 16 00 00

digest from Atmel's algorithm:
40 3D DC C0 93 A6 4B A5
01 36 7D 59 EC 8C C4 59
15 20 6D 52 A7 D5 ED 40
9B 95 31 D3 49 37 F3 F8
```

[image]

What should add with message which less than 64 bytes to get digest alike the CHIP calculation. [unfortunately yet failed any reply from ATMEL community]

Comment: I would try adding leading 0x00s, to fill up to 64 bytes. Then, if it doesn't solve the problem, trailing 0x00s. Then, if it doesn't solve the problem, leading 0xFFs. Then, if it doesn't solve the problem, trailing 0xFFs.

Comment: @barakmanos If any of these work, it is still wrong. An empty message is different from a message with all `0x00`s or `0xFF`s.

Comment: One or both of these software has a bug.

Comment: From Atmel's site: Not Recommended. Replaced by [CryptoAuthLib](http://www.atmel.com/tools/CryptoAuthLib.aspx).

Comment: @where_is_tftp I verified the error is the Atmel SHA-256 output.

Comment: FYI: With `11 CC 32 ... 16 00 00`, the expected output may be `7096F4 D63BB733 F282D474 62B75EE4 7C46AE9C F35437A6 CEC35685`.

Comment: Suggest posting you solution comment as an answer.